# Google Apps Script works when executed manually but not when launched by a trigger & no logs produced

Tags: google-apps-script, pubnub

I am using Google Apps Script (GAS) deployed as a web app in order to receive an JSON-POST API call from Nexmo (SMS) and to make REST API call to PubNub passing text of this SMS for further distribution.

When I manually execute the script everything works as expected. However, when the script is triggered by the post API call to GAS webhook, SMS data is passed to GAS but there does not seem to be a call to PubNub API.

I tried using Logger, Stackdriver, and custom logging function to a spreadsheet but there are no logs produced when script is executed by doPost(e) trigger. When executed manually logs appear as expected (no errors). I would greatly appreciate any suggestions as I am completely at a loss as to what is wrong and how to start tracking it down. Below is a simplified code:

```
//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a GET request
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("request received");
}

//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a POST request
function doPost(e) {
//  var myData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents); // below sample data analogous to what I would get from JSON-POST
  var myData = { "msisdn": "447700900001", "to": "447700900000", "messageId": "0A0000000123ABCD1", "text": "B", "type": "text", "keyword": "B", "message-timestamp": "2019-01-01T12:00:00.000+00:00" }
  var responseText = myData.text;
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("post request received");

// This is the PubNub API call
  var PUB_KEY = 'demo';
  var SUB_KEY = 'demo';
  var CHANNEL = 'poll_demo';
  var url = 'http://pubsub.pubnub.com/publish/' + PUB_KEY + '/' + SUB_KEY + '/0/' + CHANNEL + '/0/' + escape('"' + responseText + '"');
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}
```

**EDIT:**
At this point my main obstacle is that nothing appears in console.log or Logger.log even if I try to log raw post data before doing anything else with it. At the same time curl request emulating post call shows no errors, HTTP 200, and acknowledges that a post call was made.

Comment: Why are you not returning anything? The webapp triggers must return content or HTML (via the respective service): https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#requirements_for_web_apps

Comment: Thank you @tehhowch for pointing this out. I uncommented the return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput line. At this point my main obstacle is that nothing appears in console.log or Logger.log even if I try to log raw post data before doing anything else with it. At the same time curl request emulating post call shows no errors, HTTP 200, and acknowledges that a post call was made.

Comment: Have you tried using `console.log("my logging info");`?

Comment: Note that nothing after `return HtmlService....` will execute - since you called return. Probably you want something like `function doPost(e) { var props = getPropsForApi('pubnub'); useApi('pubnub', props, e.postData); return ContentService....; }` (i.e. `return` from doPost is the last thing you do)

Comment: A 200 response from PubNub at your referenced endpoint means your GET successfully published data on the PubNub network. In order to see this data on another machine, you need must initialize a subscribe on that machine, and await a new publish. If you wish to see data that was published in the past, you can programmatically fetch data using the Storage & Playback history API. You can explore this functionality in the PubNub debug console https://www.pubnub.com/docs/console

Comment: Thank you @tehhowch for pointing out that I effectively terminate the code before it can fully execute. I really appreciate your help, spent a day trying to figure it out and your insight was invaluable!

Comment: @CraigConover Yes sir, I did try both console.log and logger.log but when script is executed by a trigger they don't seem to be doing much.

Comment: Thank you @Adam for suggesting how to troubleshoot PubNub API calls. I will definitely I use this in the future! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @tehhowch for pointing out my fundamental lack of understanding how `return` works. Putting return before rest of the code was executed made remaining code invisible to the interpreter and rendered code equivalent to the following:

```
//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a GET request
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("request received");
}

//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a POST request
function doPost(e) {
//  var myData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents); // below sample data analogous to what I would get from JSON-POST
  var myData = { "msisdn": "447700900001", "to": "447700900000", "messageId": "0A0000000123ABCD1", "text": "B", "type": "text", "keyword": "B", "message-timestamp": "2019-01-01T12:00:00.000+00:00" }
  var responseText = myData.text;
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("post request received");
// PubNub inaccessible code is here
}
```